# why while loop terminate when we take input as long int type?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, long-integer

In this program, When I am giving value larger than 10^10 ,loop terminate itself and give wrong output.

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<long int>v;
    long int  x;
    int i=5;
    while(i)
        {
            cin>>x;
            v.push_back(x);
            i--;
        }
    for(long int i=v.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {

            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(4)<<sqrt(v[i])<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `10^10` is too big for a `long int` on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you're exceeding the value range of `long`.

The standard guarantees at least 32 bits for `long`. Since 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 = roughly 1000, that's 2<sup>32</sup> = 2<sup>2</sup> × (2<sup>10</sup>)<sup>3</sup> = roughly 4 × 10<sup>9</sup> values. Half of them are negative, so the upper value limit for the minimum number of bits is roughly 2×10<sup>9</sup>.

With an implementation with 64-bit `long` you would not exceed its range (can you calculate quickly the approximate range?).

---

Regarding

> **”** When I am giving value larger than 10^10 ,loop terminate itself

No, the loop doesn't terminate. But since the input operation fails `cin` is in a failure mode, which causes all further input operations to be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

This is beacause you are exceeding the max limit of Long int, this table might help.

char            1 byte  -128 to 127 or 0 to 255

unsigned char   1 byte  0 to 255

signed char     1 byte  -128 to 127

int             2 or 4 bytes    -32,768 to 32,767 or -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

unsigned int    2 or 4 bytes    0 to 65,535 or 0 to 4,294,967,295

short           2 bytes         -32,768 to 32,767

unsigned short  2 bytes         0 to 65,535

long            4 bytes         -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

unsigned long   4 bytes         0 to 4,294,967,295

**Try long long int in your code that might work. That might work i don't know its range.**

Comment: **−1** The limits given here may be true of a given implementation, but not in general. In particular the number of bits per byte can be more than 8. The `CHAR_BIT` constant from `<limits.h>` gives the number of bits per byte.

Comment: You're not the first the commit this error. For example, the authors of MIT's first open courseware on C++ also did that. I think they were students, but, students at one of the most prestigious learning institutions in the world.

Comment: Re "I don't know its range", `long long` is guaranteed to have 64 bits or more. But instead of directly using `long long`, which is a bit of a mouthful, I'd include `<stdint.h>` and use `int64_t`. It's usually *defined* as `long long`, but it's shorter and more descriptive name.